# Jewish historical novels

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, historical-figures, amoroim

Do you know any Jewish historical novels that center around the lives and times of the rabbis of the Talmud?  I know *[As a Driven Leaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_a_Driven_Leaf)* but very few others.

Comment: Akiva by Marcus Lehmann, https://www.amazon.com/Four-Who-Entered-Paradise-Novella/dp/0876685793

Comment: Good one!  But I have it and read it.

Comment: There seem to be a few about Rabbi Akiva - https://read.dukeupress.edu/tikkun/article-abstract/32/3/2/131422/The-Secret-Chord-Akiva-Life-Legend-Legacy-Rabbi?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Orchard-Yochi-Brandes/dp/9652299308/ref=sr_1_15?dchild=1&keywords=talmud&qid=1626761841&s=books&sr=1-15, https://www.amazon.com/Rav-Hisdas-Daughter-Book-Apprentice/dp/0452298091/ref=sr_1_23?dchild=1&keywords=talmud&qid=1626761841&s=books&sr=1-23

Answer (score 2):

I think a community wiki answer would be good for this question. Everyone, feel free to add your book recommendations.

**Rabbi Akiva:**

- [האסופי מנרבתא](https://www.siman-kria.co.il/product/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%90--%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A1%D7%94-%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A9?gclid=CjwKCAjwi9-HBhACEiwAPzUhHPb7u5U_E7NiXtnE5vXrvVTOL1V6h2DjNv_oOT7g0-LJT6tC0Q9FVhoCfxUQAvD_BwE) (The Foundling of Narbata) by Hadassah Klosch - Rabbi Akiva is only a secondary character in the book, but his arrest and subsequent death is a key plotline.

Answer (score 1):

[The Orchard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9652299308) by Yochi Brandes is on Rabbi Akiva.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Gadi and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Sorele Brownstein
The Gilded Cage: Queen Esther's untold story.
Narrative is through Esther's eyes, it's written very well.

Comment: Is Esther a rabbi in the Talmud?